# Slack event api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slack, slack-api

I want to integrate the slack event API using the javascript. how can I do that? I have done by using the node.js and it works fine.

I am using the slack event API to get the message from slack to my website the problem which I am facing is I am punching the data in chat by javascript receiving the data from slack is in react I need to pass the message value to my custom javascript function by reactsjs.

Below is the code i am using to get the slack message to my website this is backend code which give me the data of channel in responce:-

Backend:-

```
// Initialize using verification token from environment variables
   const createSlackEventAdapter = require('@slack/events-
    api').createSlackEventAdapter;
    const slackEvents = 
   createSlackEventAdapter(process.env.SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN || 
   '');
   const ports =  3000;

  // Attach listeners to events by Slack Event "type". See: 
   https://api.slack.com/events/message.im
   slackEvents.on('message', (event) => 
     message = event.message;
   });

   slackEvents.on('error', console.error);


   slackEvents.start(ports).then(() => {
   console.log(`server listening on port ${ports}`);
    });
```

I need to pass the event.message to a javascript function.

Comment: Please describe in more details what your want to do and what your specific issue is. In the current form, its unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have add more details

Comment: thanks. please also add the relevant part of your current code to the question

Comment: Added the node backend code which get the slack messages i need to pass the message to javascript function